# AUTimePitch or AUPitch in IOS 5

Tags: ios5, core-audio

I'm poking around the ios documentation at the moment in the core audio section.

I'm just trying to do pitch shifting without having to write my own processing callback and I'm really confused with the documentation telling me one thing and the headers saying another.

My first question is about kAudioUnitSubType_Pitch

First ,In the ios section of the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/SystemAudioUnits/SystemAudioUnits.html) the pitch unit is listed but when I try to add it to code its not listed in the code hint and in the audio unit header it says that its for desktop only. Is it possible to use this in ios 5 at all or am I looking at the wrong docs.

Second , also in the ios section of the docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AUComponentServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) I'm interested in kAudioUnitSubType_TimePitch. It is listed but states ios 2.0 through ios 2.0. Does this mean that you cant use it in ios5 ?

Could somebody give me some clarity on the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's time pitch modification AU is currently not available in iOS 5, only in the desktop Mac OS.  The early AU docs have been corrected.  The current iOS 5.x only supports a pitch resampler unit.

But there appear to be one or more commercial iOS library solutions for audio time pitch modification, if you don't want to roll your own.

ADDED later:  Only the 1st gen iPad is limited to iOS 5.x.  iOS 7 includes the NewTimePitch Audio Unit.  But this audio unit is (currently) lower in quality than the OS X TimePitch audio unit

Comment: could you point me in the right direction of the pitch resampler unit please so I check if it suits my needs.

Comment: I think dirac (http://www.dspdimension.com/technology-licensing/dirac/) has been mentioned in stackoverflow previously. But I haven't tried it.